# Spring-Boot: How to restrict the visibility of Beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, visibility, camunda

I have two custom `PlatformTransactionManager` beans injected into the Spring framework with specific `names` as follows:

```
@Bean(name = "ubldbTransactionManager")
protected PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("ubldbEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}

@Bean(name = "bpdbTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager bpdbTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("bpdbEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

A 3rd-party library has a `@Autowired protected PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;` dependency. So, the 3rd party library is not supposed to use none of the two `TransactionManagers`. However, as you see there is no `Qualifier` for the dependency injection in the external library and I get an error as follows:

```
Field transactionManager in org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.configuration.impl.DefaultDatasourceConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - bpdbTransactionManager: defined by method 'bpdbTransactionManager' in class path resource [eu/nimble/service/bp/config/BusinessProcessDBConfig.class]
    - ubldbTransactionManager: defined by method 'transactionManager' in class path resource [eu/nimble/service/bp/config/UBLDBConfig.class]
```

So, how can I restrict the visibility of the two `Beans` so that they would not be accessible by the 3rd-party library?

Comment: Does that 3rd party library interacts with any database of its own? Have you disabled DataSourceAutoConfiguration ? If that library uses TransactionManager then there must be an underlying DB for that library. Have you identified that?

Comment: I've not disabled DataSourceAutoConfiguration since the 3rd party library interacts with its own database. I'm aware of the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DefaultDatasourceConfiguration` is provided to use default Spring beans e.g. `DataSource` named `dataSource` and `PlatformTransactionManager` named `transcationManager`. It's there to glue Camunda into a Spring Boot application which be default has a single data source.

Since you have created your own `PlatformTransactionManager` beans this  disabled Spring Boot's default transaction manager bean named `transcationManager` (as per `TransactionAutoConfiguration` Spring Boot auto-configuration logic).

You most likely need to define one more `transactionManager` (and potentially `dataSource`) for Camunda's process engine, which requires it's own schema. Make sure to use the right bean name as below:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
  ...
}
```

Starting from Spring 4 the bean name is the default qualifier when auto-wiring so the new transaction manager will be wired into `DefaultDatasourceConfiguration` as it matches the field name in the class.

Alternatively don't use `DefaultDatasourceConfiguration` and roll out your own configuration if Spring Boot defaults are not working for you.

Comment: I'll try to inject a default `PlatformTransactionManager ` but I wouldn't prefer that if there is a sort of visibility restriction capability. Because, I might have reserved the default data source for the application's own database. I saw some posts mentioning package level restrictions but it seems they do not work anymore.

Comment: If you are overwriting Spring Boot defaults be prepared that Camunda integration with Spring Boot won't work. Your problem is about bean names, not visibility restrictions. If you have a custom setup you might want to roll out your own version of `DefaultDatasourceConfiguration`.

Comment: Yes, but if Camunda didn't have access to the custom `TransactionManager` it might have used the default one. But I guess it does not fit the way Spring works. I won't overwrite the defaults but try to inject also the default `PlatformTransactionManager ` which will be created by the `DataSource` instantiated for Camunda.

Comment: @suat You have recognized that you are going against Spring Boot defaults. It might be easier to write your own version of `DefaultDatasourceConfiguration` at this point.

Comment: do you have any idea how can I inject the `transactionManager` you mentioned? I mean how exactly can I create the instance. I a bit got lost in configuring Camunda? Even if I write my own `DefaultDatasourceConfiguration`, I'll still need to provide this instance. See: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter/blob/e52d13eb428279c36e1dfbb143277b8ff6af8abd/starter/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/spring/boot/starter/configuration/impl/DefaultDatasourceConfiguration.java#L16 If you want I can create a dedicated question

Comment: I ended up with my own version of `DatasourceConfiguration`. It seems to be working, but I'm not sure I've done it properly. Would you mind if you have a look at the way I created a custom `TransactionManager` at: https://justpaste.it/5agey? Thanks a lot. I'm especially not sure about the packages to be scanned. However, I couldn't find another way to initialize the `EntityManagerFactoryBean`. When I leave it empty, it generates an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Qualifier annotation 
The @Qualifier annotation is used to resolve the autowiring conflict, when there are multiple beans of same type.

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("ubldbTransactionManager")
protected PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager
```

and

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("bpdbTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager bpdbTransactionManager
```